# Unresolvable parent POM dependency in Jira's Rest Java Client

Tags: java, rest, maven, client, jira

I need to write an application, that connects to the REST API of our Jira instance and synchronizes specific data to another application of ours.

I figured this [official REST client libary](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client/src/master/) is my straightest way. Unfortunately it seems there is no ready-to-go jar dependecy I can just add to my POM.
I figured I will just build it myself and clone the repo. To enable the resoultion of Atlassian's proprietary dependencies, I added the Maven Repo Proxy to my Maven's settings.xml as suggested by
the [Atlassian Developer Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/atlassian-maven-repositories-2818705/).

Unfortunately I still can not package the API client, since the dependency of the parent POM remains unresolvable.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.pom</groupId>
    <artifactId>public-pom</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.8</version>
</parent>
```

Now, I wonder if my approach was even the correct. Is this library even meant for my usecase, or am I supposed to implement my API from scratch against the existing Jira REST endpoints since I don't develop an integrated Jira-Plugin. Or am I just missing some trivial configuration.

The addition to my settings.xml, everything else, I left untouched like in an *empty* settings.xml.

```
...
<repository>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
       <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
</repository>
...
```

I already tried to get some help from the Atlassian community itself, but they don't seem to be very responsive at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [this Atlassian resource](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JRJC/overview).
It seems that this library is more suitable for needs, and it's surely supported more actively. You can of course build your own library, but I doubt that will be any better than just sending plain requests to endpoints.
From what I found, **public-pom** looks very experimental, and isn't documented at all. If you want a quick approach - use their [documented endpoints](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/)
If you want a more architecture-oriented approach, you can build a simple library with predefined endpoints, and use something like Camel, for easy routing and logging.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it is actually exactly the one I am trying to use. If you click through the links you will find the reference to the settings.xml and the link to the Bitbucket repo, I posted.
Now if you go ahead and try to package the sources, since there seemingly is no jar available, you will end with the problem of the missing parent POM.